# How to get tensorflow 1.7 with colaboratory?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am getting

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'LayerRNNCell'

which is a change from tensorflow 1.6 to 1.7 and i have created custom cells based upon 1.7 api but google-colab itself does not seem to be in line with the latest release.

How do i upgrade 1.6.0 version of tensorflow on colaboratory to 1.7.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just using

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.7.0
```

at the beginning of your notebook?

Comment: that works with hardware accelerator set to GPU. Otherwise it rolls back to 1.6.0 (?)